# Which query is performing better if one query has lower logical reads but other query has lower relative query cost?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have two queries that give the same result.

First query :

```
Select c1.CustomerID, o1.CustomerID
From Customers As c1 
Left Join Orders As o1 On c1.CustomerID = o1.CustomerID
Where o1.CustomerID Is Null
```

Second query :

```
Select c1.CustomerID, Null As CustomerID 
From Customers As c1
Where c1.CustomerID Not In (Select CustomerID From Orders)
```

Both return the same result. But statistics for time and IO are different.

```
> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
> 
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.  
> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 10 ms, elapsed time = 10 ms.
> 
> (2 rows affected) Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0,
> physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
> physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Worktable'. Scan
> count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob
> logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table
> 'Orders'. Scan count 1, logical reads 22, physical reads 0, read-ahead
> reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead
> reads 0. Table 'Customers'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5, physical
> reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads
> 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
> 
> (1 row affected)
> 
>  SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 180
> ms.
> 
> (2 rows affected) Table 'Orders'. Scan count 1, logical reads 510,
> physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
> physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Customers'. Scan
> count 1, logical reads 5, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob
> logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
> 
> (1 row affected)
> 
>  SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 150
> ms. SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed
> time = 0 ms.
> 
>  SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

Here are the query plans :

[Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T4Rq.png)

Relative query cost for first query is 62% and that for second query is 38%. However, logical reads in first case is 22+5 = 27 where as for second case is 515.

So which query is considered to be performing better?

Comment: Logical reads are not actual reads.

Comment: Create an index on Orders.CustomerId + 2nd query

Comment: It will depend upon your pain point in the system -- cpu, memory, disk, etc. CPU time on both queries is down to < 0 ms, so the cpu load on both is probably low. All things being equal then, aim for keeping your query profile as low as possible -- that is, the fewer pages it needs to read (measured in logical reads), either from memory or disk, the less your query needs to crowd other pages out of memory.